# CSS dropdown menu using W3schools example

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm attempting to create a dropdown menu using [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp) example method, but I can't seem to get the menu to stay open when moving the cursor away from the button. At first I thought my code was wrong, so I directly copied the W3schools code to my files, but still got the same result.

CSS code:

```
.personal-dropbtn {
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.personal-dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.personal-dropdown-content {
    background: #DDD;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

.personal-dropdown-content a {
    display: block;
}

.personal-dropdown-content a:hover {
}

.personal-dropdown:hover .personal-dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    <div class="personal-dropdown">
        <button class="personal-dropbtn"><%= current_user.username %></button>
        <div class="personal-dropdown-content">
            <%= link_to 'Profil', user_path(current_user) %>
            <%= link_to 'Logg ut', destroy_user_session_path %>
            <%= link_to 'Lag quiz', new_quiz_path %>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see, I'm utilizing Ruby on Rails to create the website. I'm wondering if that might be breaking the menu in some way?
I plugged my code without the Ruby incjection into [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/34azyk69/) and it worked there, so I can only conclude that Rails might be disturbing somehow?

EDIT:
Resulting html code when loading the site:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row header">
        <div class="col xs-6 col-md-3 logo">
            <img src="/assets/logo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-9 header-content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 personal">
                    <div class="personal-dropdown pull-right">
                        <button class="personal-dropbtn">asdfasdf</button>
                        <div class="personal-dropdown-content">
                            <a href="/users/2">Profil</a>
                            <a href="/users/sign_out">Logg ut</a>
                            <a href="/quiz/new">Lag quiz</a>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the selector in which you set the display: none for the content:

```
.personal-dropbtn {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.personal-dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.personal-dropdown .personal-dropdown-content {
  background: #DDD;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.personal-dropdown:hover .personal-dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

The content is expected to disappear when you leave the personal-dropdown, if it is still happening, I can only imagine that you are leaving the dropdown when moving the mouse. It is possible that some of the elements is adding some blank spacing causing the issue?

Can you paste the resulting HTML code?

Thanks.

Comment: Changing the selector did nothing. I updated the post with the generated source code from the site.

Comment: For me, the HTML code and CSS combination is working as expected. Hovering on the button or the dropdown content keeps the dropdown open, however, when the container is left the dropdown is not visible. What is wrong on that?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/34azyk69/1/)

Comment: It works as expected when testing anywhere else than in the page code iself. There it breaks. As stated, hovering the button brings up the menu. But it's gone as soon as I leave the button. The only conclusion I can reach is that Rails somehow ruins it.

Comment: Take into account that Rails 4 is only sending the page (HTML + rest of assets) to your browser and does nothing further once the page has been loaded. I am pretty sure that some of the div you are using are adding some  spacing between the button and the dropdown. 

Give a look to the update code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/34azyk69/2/). Just adding a little space between the button and the dropdown the issue you describe is recreated. I think one of the Bootstrap classes is adding a similar spacing.